# Error: Tried to overwrite <package_path>.__ivy_ngcc_bak with an ngcc back up file, which is disallowed

Tags: angular, npm, angular9, angular-ivy

I have upgraded from Angular 8 to 9 and have enabled Ivy following all the steps [here](https://next.angular.io/guide/ivy).  When I run `npm install` a handful of my packages throw the error:

`Tried to overwrite <package_path>.__ivy_ngcc_bak with an ngcc back up file, which is disallowed`.

What does this mean and why is it happening?  I'm having a hard time finding any info on it.  I've installed the latest version for all of these packages throwing this error and I still get the error when I run `npm install`. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This is an issue regarding the ivy compiler which is the default compiler from angular 9 onwards [(read issue details)](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/32431). you can disable ivy compiler as below to avoid this error.

- Go to `tsconfig.json` and find `angularCompilerOptions`.
- Then add below

  `"angularCompilerOptions": {
  "enableIvy": false
  }`

Answer (score 1):

This can happen when you have an ivy-compiled node package and you update the node package's files.

To fix, delete all of the compilation files for the node package (eg. in `<package_path>`) that have `__ivy_ngcc_` in the filename or in the file extension, then restart Angular.